# Will unpublishing clean the empty folders as well?

Tags: publishing

In our solution, when we publish the image content they are deployed onto image servers in a folder structure. When we unpublish\update the image content then is there a way to delete the left over empty folders using Tridion? Heard it has some house keeping techniques.

Comment: How exactly is the content transferred to the image server? If this is done through a storage extension, then there will have to be something additionally done for this, if the image server is just a location in your cd_storage_conf.xml, then the Deployer/Broker should take care of cleaning up empty directories.

Comment: Just a thought but ... I recall in the past I had problems where folders didn't appear to be removed even when all published pages were unpublished - in my specific scenario I found this was (likely) as I had the folder open (eagerly watching for it to be removed) ... when performed the same unpublish (after publishing again) ensuring I had nothing connected to the folder this did, indeed, perform as Bart suggests it should.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm both @Dylan's & @Bart's answer, it should indeed delete the folder when the last page is unpublished from it.

I have just verified this with the windows service deployer, and would expect the same behavior from the other deployer types.

If you are not seeing the folder delete, double check the permissions of the user the deployer is running as. Also check the deployer log file for any error messages.

n.b. You can run the windows service deployer in command prompt, to see the debugging messages in real-time.